# Content is missing when generate PDF with puppeteer

Tags: css, node.js, puppeteer

I used puppeteer to create PDF from HTML file. As you can see from the HTML file, all the rows are visible. But when I try to generate the PDF from it, some rows at the end are missing.
Do you have any idea how to fix it? Is it an issue with styling? Or is there any configuration for puppeteer that can help fix it? All the code is available here.

https://gist.github.com/haiphan/5e5910017caeb0bf8943c1a50c462857

I'm using puppeteer "^2.1.1", node v8.17.0
[image: PDF missing rows at the end]

Comment: How you solved this issue? I am facing the same issue now. In my case, PDF height is coming correctly but the content is missing at the end. Can some one please help.